# Scrape website with javascript using cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I try to scrape data of this website:
http://ntthnue.edu.vn/tracuudiem

First, when I insert the SBD field with data 'TS4740', I can successfully get the result. However, when I try to run this code:

Here is my PHP cURL code:

```
<?php

function getData($id) {
    $url = 'http://ntthnue.edu.vn/tracuudiem';
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['sbd' => $id]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

echo getData('TS4740');
```

I just got the old page. Can anybody explain why? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you add all the necessary headers and input data. The server that is processing this request can do all kinds of checks to see if it's a "valid" form request. As such you need to spoof the request to be as close to a regular browser request as possible.

Use tools like **Chrome Dev Tools** to see both the request and respons headers that are sent between the server and your browser to better understand what you curl setup should be like. And further use a app like **Postman** to make the request simulation super easy and to see what works and not.

## Working example:

```
<?php

function getData($id) {
    $url = 'http://ntthnue.edu.vn/tracuudiem';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $postdata = 'namhoc=2015-2016&kythi_name=Tuy%E1%BB%83n+sinh+v%C3%A0o+l%E1%BB%9Bp+10&hoten=&sbd='.$id.'&btnSearch=T%C3%ACm+ki%E1%BA%BFm';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Origin: http://ntthnue.edu.vn',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer: http://ntthnue.edu.vn/tracuudiem',
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

echo getData('TS4740');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the problem is about javascript

Comment: I've got it working with a `Postman` test. I've updated my answer. Make sure you pass all the inputs from the form.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But can you explain why your code can run ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer for a better explanation.