# Curl is not working with wordpress (?p=123) redirect instead of slug

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, curl

At present, I am extracting iframe src from a wordpress site. i think, i have made a complicated code as a noob to php.

i created a php file which works like api, if we give the url it will output, the iframe in it.

```
EX. file_get_contents('api.php?url=' . $url);
```

in that api.php i used a php function from this site, http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/10/20/how-to-extract-html-tags-and-their-attributes-with-php/

I have added a php function to make a curl request, which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090939/scrape-website-with-javascript-using-curl).

```
function getFRMsrc($id) {
$src = $_GET['url'];
$src = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($src)); 
$src = html_entity_decode($src,null,'UTF-8');
    $frmch = curl_init($src);
    $postdata = 'namhoc=2015-2016&kythi_name=Tuy%E1%BB%83n+sinh+v%C3%A0o+l%E1%BB%9Bp+10&hoten=&sbd='.$id.'&btnSearch=T%C3%ACm+ki%E1%BA%BFm';
    curl_setopt($frmch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($frmch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($frmch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($frmch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Origin: samesite used for not getting blocked',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer: samesite used for not getting blocked',
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($frmch);

    curl_close($frmch);

    return $result;
}
```

and for extracting iframe source, i used following as per the function in above mentioned site.

```
$frmsrc = getFRMsrc('TS4740');

$nodes = extract_tags( $frmsrc, 'iframe' );
foreach($nodes as $link){
    echo $link['attributes']['src'] , '';
}
```

the above setup is working fine with url like `http://targetsite.com/post_slug/`

As, they found that i have been doing this for some reason. They keep changing the post slugs. That is a very big headache for me to update everytime.

So, i wanted to use wordpress short urls which are like `http://targetsite.com/?p=123` As those links are permanent.

but above code is not working with the wordpress redirect from ?p=123 to /post_slug/. It is outputting blank.

I also tried URL-encoding it but no use.

Please, help me with this problem. i need to make it work as fast as possible.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to TRUE http://php.net/function.curl-setopt

Comment: show us the html they use, the html that you try to parse... also your parsing method is horrible, you should try DOMDocument, not that regex-urldecode-utf8encode - again, show us the HTML, and ill show you how

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do this job using DOMDocument. i will let you know, if that worked for this case.